# How to filter data in spring

Tags: spring, postgresql

I have a method that returns a list, how can I filter this data at the level in the spring repository or at the level of sql queries, I need the filtered data to come to this method

```
public List<Mark> getMarksByUser(){
List<Mark> marks = markService.getMarksByUser(AuthenticationController.selfUserName());
```

}

Can you please show an example of a filter, for example, over the createDate field from mark

```
public class Mark extends BaseEntity<Integer> {
private String text;
private String sku;
private Date dateCreated;
```

Comment: use like this markService.getMarksByUserAndDateCreated(AuthenticationController.selfUserName(),dateCreated);

Comment: what do you think about my answer?can you check?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("SELECT mark FROM Mark mark where mark.dateCreated = :dateCreated AND mark.deleted = :deleted")
List<Mark> findByDateCreatedAndDeleted(@Param("dateCreated") Date dateCreated,
                                                @Param("deleted") Boolean deleted);
```

Comment: please run the code and tell. validate your answer by executing it

Comment: I have some bugs in the code, I'll fix it, send it here.